# Where did ConcurrentDictionary.ForEach go?

Tags: c#, foreach, unity-container, concurrentdictionary

Context: C#, VS, Unity

We updated Unity from 4.0.1 to 5.11.3.
Now the ForEach-method on a ConcurrentDictionary is no longer found.

I suspect I'm missing an other Nuget-package or that it just changed namespace - I have googled but still can't find any solution.

Does anyone know where it went?

It seems that Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2 disappeard with the newer Unity, but to where?

Comment: You seem to speek about a different `Unity` ... **not [Unity3D](https://unity.com) the game engine** ... is your tag correct? Also this seems rather `c#` specific and not related to a certain library

Comment: Unity doesnt seem to have 5.11.3, 5.6.7 seems the last https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, its c# Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing an extension.

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}
```